# Only Codeigniter callback function is working rest validation rules are being ingnored

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple registration page where a small validation whether CPF Number exist or not is to be checked from database along with some validation rules. However after submitting the form only callback function is working from the validation rules and rest rules are being ignored like required|trim... etc.

In My Controller (Validation Rules):

```
if ($this->input->post()) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpf','CPF','trim|required|numeric|max_length[15]|callback_checkIfExist[cpf]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE) {
        $rb = random_bytes(8);
        $randPass = bin2hex($rb);
        // TODO: Store hashed password in db
        // mail new password for login
        // login and update password
    }
}
$this->load->view($page,$data);
```

In My Controller (Callback Function):

```
public function checkIfExist($cpf){
    if (!$data['employee']=$this->HomeModel->getEmployeeData($cpf)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkIfExist','No data found with this {field}');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In My Model :

```
public function getEmployeeData($cpf){
  # returning only 1 row of particular employee
  $this->db->where('e_cpf',$cpf);
  $this->db->where('e_b_id',Me::$bid);
  $qry = $this->db->get('employees');
  if ($row = $qry->row()) {
    return $row;
  }
}
```

In My View :

```
<form class="user" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control form-control-user <?=(form_error('cpf'))?'is-invalid':'is-valid'?>" id="exampleInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter CPF Number ..." value="<?=set_value('cpf')?>">
        <p class="p-2"><?=form_error('cpf')?></p>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong.  What data are you using to produce this fault?

Comment: Any data which can create faults on grounds of : trim|required|numeric|max_length[15], If input lefts blank it does not show any error, if non-numeric values are entered it even does not show any error and so on however the callback function is working properly.